# Centering a form without using width

Tags: html, css

How do I center a From without giving it a width value?

I've tried using `margin-left:auto;` and `margin-right:auto;` and `margin:0 auto;`,

but none of them seem to work well with forms. Only widths seem to do the trick.

**Code:**

```
form 
{
    width:400px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Form? May be div or something else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply use `text-align: center;` in your `form` css

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KCm87/6/)

```
form {
   text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Form (and likewise layer) element takes all available width unless you specify some width (width or max-width) value. Therefore you cannot center a form without specifying a width to it.

Answer (score 0):

Using display : block will make form full width to it's parent..
Use display: inline-block
Here is Quick Way To do it:

If form is in body tag Apply this Css

Here is Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KCm87/13/

```
body{
    text-align:center;
}

form {
    display:inline-block    
}
```

Good Luck :)
Hope It Helps You. :)